# Set same Layouts for all Installed languages in Cs-Cart

Tags: layout, cs-cart

I am working on a CScart project with multiple languages. I noticed that when i change the layout for English, the change doesnt reflect on other language layouts. Is there a way to do this as i have multiple languages and multiple changes to be made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you havent defined each language as a seperate storefront, you can just click the checkbox in the block editor to 'apply' to all languages. You could also create static blocks (/templates/bocks/static_templates/*) with language variables and add them in the layout.

The last option would be to export and import the layout using the provided XML import / export tool.

Kind regards,